# Render changes quickly on web

Tags: reactjs, heroku, port, host

**Faster way to render changes to launched app**

I am using heroku to host my portfolio app, but everytime I make changes, I need to repush everything and it takes a while. Is there a faster way than editing and pushing?

Comment: Do you have a local setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid a push each time you want to test something inside your Heroku app you can run your app locally before you push it: [Running Apps Locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local).